# Error while assigning module output to the "name" property of resources in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have a bicep module that outputs some prefixes and a couple of others that function similarly. I want to use the output of this module to dynamically construct variables such as appResourceGroupName  and set the "name" property of a Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups resource. However, when I attempt to do so, I encounter the following error:

`This expression is being used in an assignment to the "name" property of the "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups" type, which requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment. You are referencing a variable which cannot be calculated at the start ("appResourceGroupName" -> "resourcePrefixes" -> "resourcePrefixesModule"). Properties of resourcePrefixesModule which can be calculated at the start include "name".`

This is a sample of my bicep code

##### resourcePrefixesModule

```
var resourcePrefixes = {
  storageAccount: 'st'
}

output resourcePrefixes object = resourcePrefixes
```

##### main bicep

```
module resourcePrefixesModule 'infrastructure/modules/resourcePrefixesModule.bicep' = {
  name: 'resourcePrefixes'
  scope: resourceGroup('subscription')
}

var resourcePrefixes = resourcePrefixesModule.outputs.resourcePrefixes

var appResourceGroupName = toLower('${resourcePrefixes.resourceGroup}-${thisEnvironment.environmentShortName}-${thisLocation.shortName}-${appName}')

// App-specific resources
resource appResourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: appResourceGroupName
  location: location
  tags: {
    environment: environment
  }
  dependsOn: [
    resourcePrefixesModule
  ]  
}
```

I understand that the error is caused because the "name" property of Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups needs a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment, and I know that the value from the "appInfrastrucutreModule" output cannot be resolved at that point as they run concurrently.

Is there any way to use the output of a module to dynamically set the "name" property for a resource in Bicep? If not, what are the possible workarounds to achieve this behavior? I tried relating them together using dependsOn, so that the resource wouldn't be created until the module has completed, but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like the [shared variable file pattern.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/patterns-shared-variable-file)

Instead of using modules to define the resource prefixes. Use the shared json file which will contain resource prefixes and then load it into the variable using the loadJsonContent, something like in the following [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/patterns-shared-variable-file#example-1-naming-prefixes).

Comment: We had been using json files previously when we were sharing the bicep using Git Submodules, however we are transitioning to using an ACR, which can only store the .bicep files

Comment: We are trying to avoid having to make copies of the JSON files across repositories rather trying to have a common one that can be referenced

Comment: The error says: "You are referencing a **variable** which cannot be calculated at the start" 
Will it throw the same error If you change the var in the resourcePrefixesModule definition to the **parameter** with the default value and output it?

`param resourcePrefixes object = {
  storageAccount: 'st'
}
output resourcePrefixes object = resourcePrefixes`

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I ended up going in a different direction, wasn't able to get this working but was able to get around it by using Organization level GitHub variables rather than modules

Comment: so instead of storing this configuration in the source code repository, they are added in the GitHub as the Organization level GitHub variables and then in your bicep referred using the readEnvironmentVariable function? whenever someone needs to run the bicep from the local environment the same set of environment variables need to be present in the OS.

Comment: no we construct a bicepparams json file in the GHA, using the Org variables and pass that into the arm deploy action.